# Defining an unspecified type to a static variable inside of a class

Tags: c#, mongodb, reflection, visual-studio-2019, .net-standard

I am making a simple and specific file for use in several of my projects so I need to be able to simply 'Plug-N-play' so-to-say.

Working with MongoDB (I don't want comments about swapping to different storage solutions.), I am fetching a collection with type to cast to, however storing it within the actual class locally rather than passing it as a return method.

```
public static IMongoCollection<object> ConnectedCollection;
```

```
public async Task Connect<TDoc>(string ConnectionString, string Database, string Collection)
{
    //Do some stuff here;
    //some more stuff;
    //Get collection here: 
    var MongoCollection = ConnectedDatabase.GetCollection<TDoc>(Collection);
    /// MongoCollection returns a collection of TDoc, as specified within the method,
    /// now to cast it to a static variable defined outside of the method
    ConnectedCollection = MongoCollection;
}
```

For obvious reasons it can't be object, I need to have ConnectedCollection be of type `IMongoCollection<TDoc>` however, as it is not an actual class but a unspecified type being cast into the method, it doesn't exist, How would I allow it to remain as a static collection within, without creating an accessible class for this file.

Comment: why in the world would you ever wanna do that? your `ConnectedCollection` static variable is useless since it doesn't retain the type info. have a look at [this library](https://mongodb-entities.com/) for a ready to use solution.

Comment: @DĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ While I appreciate the link and will definitely check this out, I wouldn't have posted the question, were it not something I would want to do, I can understand the notion of it to be odd, however without going into a large amount of detail as to what the projects I need it for are, it is necessary.

Comment: You can't use object for collection template. You can use BsonDocument but you lose the automatic serialization/deserialization and you have to do it yourself.